# Is there a way to exclude a specific raw resource from an external dependency that is included when i build my android app bundle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, android-app-bundle

I'm using a library A in my app that in turn also uses another library B. Developers of library B left a raw resource used for testing purposes that is not used used during production but takes up 1mb which is a significant portion of my app bundle.

I want to exclude this resource when i build my app bundle.

I have tried using

```
packagingOptions {
     
 exclude '/res/raw/file_name.mp3'
 }
```

and

```
aaptOptions {
 ignoreAssetsPattern "!file_name.mp3"

}
```

But none of them have worked so far.

Is there a way to do this through gradle or any other method ?.